# Error after installing nuget package in asp.net MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors, nuget-package

When i install CORS Nuget package (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors), Following error shows (TemporaryGeneratedFile .....),

> Error 112 SA1633 : CSharp.Documentation : The file has no header, the
>   header Xml is invalid, or the header is not located at the top of the
>   file. E:\~~~~~~~~\My
>   Projects\Development\Web\~~~\ServiceLayer\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs    1   1   ServiceLayer

have anybody encountered it before?

**Edit:**
There is this stylecop enabled in the project.

Comment: try clean/build or close visual studio and open again.

Comment: Tried everything :-(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a StyleCop issue, see the link for a fix
http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1633.html